# C++ operator ','

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Comma Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

what is result of operator ',' by standard? Last argument? 
in code like this, for example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

while(a,b);
```

or using it like this is not allowed? MSVS thiks that result is b, is it true?

sorry for duplicating, did not know how this operator called in english )

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator

Comment: @ChrisF: I found your reasoning very weak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence of statements is executed and the return value is the evaluation of the final statement.

Comment: Is it a statement or an expression?

Answer (score 7):

The comma operator always returns its last argument, unless the operator is overloaded.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "unless overloaded"

Answer (score 3):

The result of the ',' operator is the last evaluated expression, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `,` operator is its right-hand operand, i.e. the subexpression that *follows* `,`.

Operator `,` is left-associative, meaning that if you have a chain of several `,` operators with operands and no braces, then the last subexpression in the chain is the result.